# sum two columns from two tables with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sum, union

I have two tables as shown below:

```
Table1

ID count
2   33
4   89
```

```
Table 2

ID count name color
2   31   Lily  Red
3   77   Jam   Blue
```

I want to join the two tables and sum count based on ID and get the following table

```
Expected table

ID count name color
2   64   Lily  Red
3   77   Jam   Blue
4   89   NULL  NULL
```

Can I do it with only one simple SQL query?

These two tables might be large, so the query should be as "simple" as possible. Many thanks.

Comment: Are the counts in the sample output correct?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to sum the count based on ID.

Comment: how did ID 2 sum count = 120, and ID 3 sum count = 110 ?
Shoudn't it be ID 2 sum count = 64 and ID 3 sum count = 77 ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have corrected the numbers.

Comment: I'm really sorry for the confusion. I have corrected the numbers.

Comment: Looks like a simple full outer join plus aggregation. MySQL doesn't support full outer joins, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, SUM(`count`) `count`, MAX(name) name, MAX(color) color
FROM ( SELECT ID, `count`, NULL name, NULL color
       FROM table1
       UNION ALL
       SELECT ID, `count`, name, color
       FROM table2 ) subquery
GROUP BY ID
```

?

Answer (score 0):

First of all,ID must be the primary key.
This should be what you want:
select id,sum(count),max(name),max(color) from (
select id,count,null as name,null as color from Table1
union all
select id,count,name,color from Table2) t
group by id

Comment: Must be the primary key for which of the tables? And your query is the same as the one Akina posted twenty minutes ago in his answer.

Comment: "Must be the primary key for which of the tables?" Actually,name and color for each ID are unique will be OK. And your query is the same as the one Akina posted twenty minutes ago in his answer.-----Net lag for this.